# Ruby Form Partials with Locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Ok, trying to break up a form into separate erb files, I've seen others on here successfully passing the form variable into the render partial locals => {}, but for whatever reason, it's being a real stick in the mud for me. Let's see who can fix this 'undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#Class:0x0000000018a619a0:0x000000002c119910>' error:

```
<% @modName = locals[:moduleName] %>
<% @record = locals[:record] %>
<% @id = locals[:id] %>
<% @OpNo = locals[:opno] %>
<% @modLower = locals[:moduleName].downcase %>

<%= form_for Command.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:Code, Command.where(FLD: @modName), :Code, :Definition, options ={prompt: true }, html_options = {:onchange => "updateSpecificForm(this.value)", :id=> "command_Cmd"}) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :mod, :value => @modName %>
    <br /><br />
        <div id='specific_form' style='display:none'>
            <%= render :partial => 'layouts/' + @modLower, :locals => {:f => f} %>
        </div>
<% end %>

<script>
    function updateSpecificForm(selected_val) {
        $('#specific_form').show();
    }
</script>
```

then the partial (which is where 'f' isn't recognized):

```
<%= f.hidden_field :mod, :value => @modName %>
    <%= f.label :year, 'Year' %>
        {more form stuff}
        <%= f.submit 'Approve' %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is the file where you have the initial form a partial itself ? I am working on an app with nested partials and forwarding locals has been a challenge for me too.

Comment: @Maxence great question, it is indeed a partial too.

Comment: I'm gonna wager this falls into the category slop errors - you're not running the code you think you are. There is no magic trick to passing locals to partials and it works exactly as documented. I would start by cleaning this code up - use the colon syntax instead of hashrockets and consider naming your variables, attributes etc in a way that won't cause other devs to get a stroke (which means `snake_case` EVERYTHING but ClassNames and CONSTANTS).

Comment: Also remove `options =` and `html_options =`. You don't need to be assigning local variables.

Comment: @max, neither helpful, or correct. Our company conventions are fine, I foobar'd a lot of this down for basic readability and focus on the actual problem, and the f.collection_select in this ruby -v syntax requires the hashed options.

Comment: @SeanGillespie the comment wasn't whether or not the `Hash` options were necessary it was that the assignment was not. e.g. remove the assignment (`xxxx =`) not the the `Hash`, along with basic commentary about the fact that ruby convention is to use `snake_case` not `camelCase` when naming variables. Both comments are not "answers" but rather guidance regarding ruby style guidelines. Personally I would have added a rails recommendation against assigning instance variables in the view.

Comment: Additionally I would note that in partial view 1 use you the `locals` hash to access the local variables, have you considered the same for the partial view 2, e.g. `locals[:f]` rather than just `f`?